# Improving execution speed of Screen Brightness Script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, xorg

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness $(bc -l <<<"$(sed 's/Brightness: //' <<<$(xrandr --prop --verbose | grep Brightness)) $(if [ "$1" = "+" ];then echo +;else echo -;fi) 0.1")
```

I currently have this code set up to a keyboard shortcut in XFCE on my Arch system, and it works great to adjust brightness up or down 0.1 notches. Only problem is, it's slow enough to take a second or so to execute, and pressing multiple times is worse and can slow the whole computer a bit.

How would you improve the code? (I'm pretty new to shell scripting, so I'm also partly asking this to see the process by which code I write cold be optimized.)

EDIT: Okay, so I followed drewbenn's suggestion of profiling and got this:
time xrandr -q --verbose > /dev/null
real    0m1.746s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.000s

The query, then, was the biggest issue. I changed it so that it would store the current brightness level in a file somewhere and the shortcut keys would run the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
val=$(cat ~/.bright_key_folder/lvl)
if ( [ "$1" == "+" ] && [[ $(bc -l  ~/.bright_key_folder/lvl
    xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness $(cat ~/.bright_key_folder/lvl)
elif ( [ "$1" == "-" ] && [[ $(bc -l  0") == 1 ]] )
then
    bc -l  ~/.bright_key_folder/lvl
    xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness $(cat ~/.bright_key_folder/lvl)
fi
```

Then on startup it resets brightness and the file value both to 1.

Comment: Try `xbacklight`. It may or may not work for (I think they go through different mechanisms and not all drivers support both). It may or may not be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If code is *already working* but running too slowly, the next step is to start profiling. When shell scripting, you can use `time` (try `help time` to see its help page) to see how long each command takes to run.

I think `bc` should be very fast; `sed` against one line should also be very fast; and `grep` should be pretty quick, too, so I decided to try profiling the two `xrandr` commands on my system. I just wanted some quick estimates, so I tried executing the commands individually (instead of, say, wrapping them in a script to run them dozens of times to get an average):

```
$ time xrandr --prop --verbose >/dev/null

real    0m0.428s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s
$ time xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.9

real    0m0.117s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.008s
$
```

If you get similar results, your query might be what's taking the most time.

Comment: Thanks! The query was indeed taking the most time -- sometimes a full 2 seconds -- so I stored the value elsewhere. `time`'s a useful command, glad to have learned it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one thing, you are running three separate external programs when one would be enough. You could do all the parsing and arithmetic in `awk` for example:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness $(xrandr --prop --verbose | 
    awk "/Brightness:/{print \$2 $1 0.1; exit}")
```

The `exit` in the awk script ensures that it doesn't need to parse the whole output of `xrandr --prop --verbose` and exits after the first match for `Brightness:`. Then, since the `awk` command is in double quotes, the `$1` is expanded to the argument given to the script while the `\$2` refers to the second field in `awk` because it is escaped.

You could also try using a faster shell. If your default is `bash`, try running the script with `dash`.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it was what ended up solving the problem for me, but this was what I was looking for initially and what others who see the problem will find. Thank you for responding -- once I've enough reputation I'll be sure to come back and at least +1 the answer.